# Change P element to update on new image select javascript

Tags: javascript, html, exif

I was wondering if anyone could help give some advice on how to make the p tags pic info and map link update the displayed information when selecting an image after one has already been selected. What would I need to add or change to make this happen. The code runs a basic script that retrieves exif data from images if there is any on it and produces a link to google maps showing where the location is as well as tell the user when and what time the photo was taken and what device it was taken on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>EXIF</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p><input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
  <p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
  <p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
  <br>
  <p id="pic-info"></p>
  <p id="map-link"></p>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="exif.js"></script>
  <script>
    var loadFile = function(event) {
      var image = document.getElementById('output');
      image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
  </script>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("output").onclick = function() {

      EXIF.getData(this, function() {

        myData = this;

        console.log(myData.exifdata);

        document.getElementById('pic-info').innerHTML = 'This photo was taken on ' + myData.exifdata.DateTime + ' with a ' + myData.exifdata.Make + ' ' + myData.exifdata.Model;

        // Calculate latitude decimal
        var latDegree = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator;
        var latMinute = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator;
        var latSecond = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].numerator;
        var latDirection = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitudeRef;

        var latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);
        console.log(latFinal);

        // Calculate longitude decimal
        var lonDegree = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator;
        var lonMinute = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator;
        var lonSecond = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].numerator;
        var lonDirection = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef;

        var lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);
        console.log(lonFinal);

        document.getElementById('map-link').innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/' + latFinal + ',' + lonFinal + '" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>';

      });
    }



    function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {

      var dd = degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600);

      if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1;
      }

      return dd;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can't stop the click handler, but we can check for the value in the "pic-info" on click whether it is a previous value and skip the value update for "pic-info" as well as "map-link".

```
// code here for updation 
}

<script>
    document.getElementById("output").onclick = function() {

      EXIF.getData(this, function() {

        myData = this;

        console.log(myData.exifdata);

 if(document.getElementById('pic-info').innerHTML === ('This photo was taken on ' + myData.exifdata.DateTime + ' with a ' + myData.exifdata.Make + ' ' + myData.exifdata.Model) )
{

        document.getElementById('pic-info').innerHTML = 'This photo was taken on ' + myData.exifdata.DateTime + ' with a ' + myData.exifdata.Make + ' ' + myData.exifdata.Model;

        // Calculate latitude decimal
        var latDegree = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[0].numerator;
        var latMinute = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[1].numerator;
        var latSecond = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitude[2].numerator;
        var latDirection = myData.exifdata.GPSLatitudeRef;

        var latFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(latDegree, latMinute, latSecond, latDirection);
        console.log(latFinal);

        // Calculate longitude decimal
        var lonDegree = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[0].numerator;
        var lonMinute = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[1].numerator;
        var lonSecond = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitude[2].numerator;
        var lonDirection = myData.exifdata.GPSLongitudeRef;

        var lonFinal = ConvertDMSToDD(lonDegree, lonMinute, lonSecond, lonDirection);
        console.log(lonFinal);

        document.getElementById('map-link').innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/' + latFinal + ',' + lonFinal + '" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>';

}
      });
    }


  </script>
```

Comment: how would I update/ skip the values? Is there any way you could point me in the right direction? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Oracle22 - I have modified the code above with the condition handled. You can check if that resolves your problem, mark as answer if it do so

Comment: I fixed the issue another way I just added a refresh page button. The code didnt seem to do anything. Thank you for your help though I really appreciate it.